# MRPT ROS NODE: 2D Nav Goal in rviz not working

Tags: navigation, ros, mobile-robot-toolkit

I recently started using mrpt-ros-pkg and I launched the file using:

```
roslaunch mrpt_reactivenav2d reactive_nav_demo_with_mvsim.launch
```

Everything is working fine except that I cannot get the robot to move using 2D Nav Goal on rviz.
I get the data published to `/move_base_simple/goal` topic, but the robot does not move.

However when I add a panel to rviz and use Teleop with the topic `/cmd_vel`, I can navigate the robot around (without defining goal positions)

Comment: Double check where `move_base` is publishing the velocity commands it computes and whether that matches `/cmd_vel`.

Comment: @mikkola
Here is what happens: 
the data is published to `/cmd_vel`, but it is always 0.

The target coordinates are saved in `multiple_targets` and `target[0]` gives the correct goal coordinates.

However, Single Target still has zeros as coordinates and this is what gets sent to `/cmd_vel`